# openCart() function for Shopify Buy Button JS does not work

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk, buybutton.js

I like to set up a Shopify shop via a simple HTML/CSS/JS/PHP website structure, where I include the highly customizable [Shopify Buy Button JS library](https://shopify.github.io/buy-button-js).

I followed the tutorial, and everything is set up correctly, as I can fetch and display all my products, which I have set up via the Shopify dashboard.

The default styles and iFrames of the Shopify UI elements (`cart`, `drawer`, `buy-button`, etc.) do not match the style and UX of my website, therefore I want to customize them via css. I deactivated the `iFrames` of most elements via the directive `"iframe: false"`, and this works properly.

I also want to create a customized `toggle` button, that opens the `cart` (instead of the classic toggle button form Shopify, that is fixed to the middle of the right side of the screen).

The weird thing is, I'm not able to open the `cart` via `ui.openCart()`, as mentioned in the docs. I'm able to open the cart via `ui.openCart()` when I do it with a `setTimout (3s)`, but I'm not able to do so via a `jQuery click event`. What am I doing wrong?

My code so far:

```
<script src="//sdks.shopifycdn.com/buy-button/1.0.0/buybutton.js"></script>
<script>
var client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
  domain: 'domain.myshopify.com',
  storefrontAccessToken: '2b3xxxxxxxxjh5', // previously apiKey, now deprecated
});

ui = ShopifyBuy.UI.init(client);

ui.createComponent('product', {
  id: 23xxxxxx56,
  node: document.getElementById('my-product'),
  options: {
    "product": {
      "iframe": false
    },
    toggle: {
      "iframe": false
    }
  }
});

// -- this does not work --
$('#shoppingCartDropdownInvoker').click(function(){
  ui.openCart();
});

// -- this does work --
setTimeout(function(){
  ui.openCart();
}, 3000);
</script>
```

The code for `#shoppingCartDropdownInvoker` is:

```
<a id="shoppingCartDropdownInvoker" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-text-secondary" href="javascript:;" role="button">
  <span class="fas fa-shopping-cart btn-icon__inner"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: post the html of shoppingCartDropdownInvoker

Comment: My first guess would be: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: @Unknown I've updated the question with the HTML code of ’shoppingCartDropdownInvoker’

Comment: I have copy/pasted your code and it works fine for me, check if there is an error in developer tools when you click on the link

Comment: @Unknown Thank you for trying. I also tried my above code in a new plain HTML file, but it does not work either. That's really strange. I also tried this with a different browser.

Comment: is there an error in developer tools?

Comment: @Unknown no, nothing. When I insert a console.log("click"); statement, this works fine. I also tried the above code (and a plain HTML file) with a basic 'javascript click handler', instead of 'jQuery', but this does not work either. I'm running this thing with XAMPP on localhost.

Comment: hmm.. try adding console.log(ui) to the click handler to see what functions can be called on UI, I cannot find the openCart function in the documentation from a quick look

Comment: @Unknown The strange thing is that it works perfectly with the 'setTimeout' function

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the event from bubbling up the chain.
Add event.stopPropagation as shown

```
$('#shoppingCartDropdownInvoker').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  ui.openCart();
});
```

Comment: Hi, I came across this issue as well and your solution helped a lot. But when I use the buy button on the product and add the product to the cart and trigger the shopping-cart icon to show the cart, the cart appears empty. Unless I go to another page and click then only it appears. What could be the issue?